# Using Trie to Store Word Counts

Tags: c, trie

Goal is to read a web page, store all words in a trie with each node containing one letter and a count of the number of characters, print the words and number of occurrences. I keep getting a segmentation fault and I think the issue is in one of these functions. Thanks!

```
struct trieNode *indexPage(const char *url) {
    if (url == NULL) {
        return NULL;
        printf("Web link must be provided.");
    }
    //get text from page and check return value
    char *page = NULL; 
    int bytesRead = getText(url, page, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (page == NULL) {
        printf("Page could not be indexed.");
        return NULL;
    }

    //index buffer into separate words
    int i = 0;
    char *word = NULL;
    struct trieNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct trieNode));

    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Node memory could not be allocated.");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (i < bytesRead) {
        while (isalpha(page[i])) {
            word[i] = page[i];
        }
        addWordOccurrence(word, sizeof(word), i);
        i++;
    }
    return node;
}

//Create space for node in heap and add to trie structure
int addWordOccurrence(const char* word, const int wordLength, int index) {
    if (word == NULL) 
        return -1;

    //allocate memory for new node
    struct trieNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct trieNode));

    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Node memory could not be allocated.");
        return -2;
    }

    //recursively add characters to trie and 
    //increase count
    if (index < wordLength) {
        setNodeData(node->child[index], word[index]);
        node->count++;
    }
    addWordOccurrence(word, wordLength, index + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Using gdb I found the fault may be coming from the print function, possibly when trying to access pointers.

```
//Prints contents
void printTrieContents(struct trieNode *root) {
    //if child is found with a non zero count 
    //add child character to string
    char *word = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if ((root->count) && (root->child[i])) {
            word[i] = i + 'a';
            printTrieContents(root->child[i]);
        }
    }
    if (root->child == NULL) {
        printf("%s: %d", word, root->count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you learned using your debugger?  It should tell you exactly where the bug is hitting.  If you want more help though, you'll need to provide a [mcve] that we can copy/paste to run locally.

Comment: @StephenNewell I made an edit to my post after some more debugging, I think the segmentation fault is coming from trying to access pointers.

Comment: We still cannot compile and run the code — so it is still not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  It would also be desirable to have sample input and the expected output (and perhaps the actual output) for the sample input.

Comment: `addWordOccurrence` leaks memory like a sieve leaks rainwater. Look at the allocation of `node`.  *Why* is it being allocated?? the only place it is used for the rest of the function is the deref + indexing with `setNodeData(node->child[index], word[index]);` and `node->count++;`.  The node pointer itself is never put in any data structure, or saved in any out-parameter. I strongly suggest that lovely little nugget is *directly* related to your problem. I cannot say definitively without a proper [mcve], which, though asked, you've not provided. Best of luck.

Comment: @rakers, pro tip: a segmentation fault is *almost always* related to pointer use.  You're not telling us anything we didn't already know when you guess that this is so in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

- in `indexPage`, `while (isalpha(page[i])) { word[i] = page[i]; }` is potentially an infinite loop.
- in `printTrieContents`, `word[i] = i + 'a'` dereferences a null pointer as `word` is never allocated.
- `addWordOccurrence` always recurses, even after reaching the last character. There is no need for recursion, use a loop and a proper test.
- more algorithmic issues: the code needs a lot a work.

Answer (score 0):

superficially, it looks like addWordOccurrence(word, sizeof(word), i); should be addWordOccurrence(word, sizeof(word), 0); - the last parameter being the index of each letter that is handled in the recursion.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but it doesn't look like this issue explains the OP's segfault, which is the subject of the question posed.  If you don't mean for this to answer the question posed, then it should be a comment, not and answer.

Comment: I was assuming that infinite recursion blew his stack and caused the fault.

Comment: It would have been (and maybe still is) appropriate to make that explicit in this answer.  However, I'm not seeing how you conclude that that error would produce an unbounded recursion.  On the other hand, there in fact is an unbounded recursion, quite independently of the value of that argument.